# Get CheckBox Dynamically Created In Dynamically Created GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

i have a problem that i searched alot but no working answer
the problem is: i created dynamically gridview and then added dynamically created checkboxes to the gridview and its added but when iam trying to get the checkbox status (checked or not ) i cant reach the check box
please help me and thanks for this greate site

```
 Dim MessagesTable As DataTable = Recipient.CreateInboxMessagesTable(LoginName, WhatToShow)
    Dim Tbl As New DataTable
    Dim Col As DataColumn
    Dim Row As DataRow

    Col = New DataColumn("ID", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("Select", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("Sender", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("Subject", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("ReceiveDate", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("Privacy", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("ImportanceLevel", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("JustDate", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("LastReplyID", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("Status", GetType(Integer)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    Col = New DataColumn("From", GetType(String)) : Tbl.Columns.Add(Col)
    For Each TRow As DataRow In MessagesTable.Rows
        Row = Tbl.NewRow
        Row("ID") = TRow.Item("ID_Rec")
        'Row("Select") = New CheckBox
        Row("Sender") = Member.GetUserName(TRow.Item("From_Msg"))
        Row("Subject") = TRow.Item("Subject_Msg") & " =+-+= " & Message.HTMLToText(TRow.Item("Body_Msg"))
        Row("ReceiveDate") = Recipient.Convert24TimeTo12(TRow.Item("ReceiveDate_Rec")).Substring(11)
        Row("Privacy") = TRow.Item("Privacy_Msg")
        Row("ImportanceLevel") = TRow.Item("ImportanceLevel_Msg")
        Row("JustDate") = TRow.Item("ReceiveDate_Rec")
        Row("LastReplyID") = TRow.Item("LastReplyID_Msg")
        Row("Status") = TRow.Item("Status_Msg")
        Row("From") = TRow.Item("From_Msg")
        Tbl.Rows.Add(Row)
    Next
    aGrid.DataSource = Tbl
    aGrid.DataBind()
```

that is how i create my grid view and code below how i add the checkbox

```
 For Each GVRow As GridViewRow In aGrid.Rows
                   Dim CB As New CheckBox
        GVRow.Cells(1).Controls.Add(CB)
    Next
```

and this how i tried to get checkbox status but it did not worked

```
 Protected Sub btnCompleted_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompleted.Click
    For Each Row As GridViewRow In gvInbox.Rows
        Dim cbSelect As CheckBox = DirectCast(Message.FindControlRecursive(Row, "CB"), CheckBox)
        'If cbSelect.Checked = True Then

        'End If
    Next
End Sub
```

thank you

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: no because i trace the code and stop it when it failed to fetch the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for my problem by adding templateField and item template to HTML Code GridView and then it will found the checkbox control

```
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect" runat="server"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

All code looks good. But you added Checkbox to gridview without any ID.

```
For Each GVRow As GridViewRow In aGrid.Rows
        Dim CB As New CheckBox
        CB.ID = "chkRow" // Is the ID for checkbox
        AddHandler CB.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckedChaged // Could add event to the checkbox
        CB.AutoPostBack = True // make Autopostback to true to handle postback
        GVRow.Cells(1).Controls.Add(CB) // then add your control to specific position
Next
```

You have to create checkbox instance then set the attribute (ID,Autopostback) value, so that you could fetch control value using that specific ID

```
 For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox) //same ID to find that control
            If chkRow.Checked Then
              //Your Logic
          End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: thanks Rojalin Sahoo for your reply. i added ID to Checkbox but still cant fetch the checkbox